# Level set for the function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, surfaces

Draw or describe the level surface and an intersection of the graph for the function $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x, y, z) \rightarrow x^2+y^2$$

I have done the following:

The level surfaces are defined by $$\{(x, y, z) \mid x^2+y^2=c\}$$

- For $c=0$ we have that $x^2+y^2=0$. So for $c=0$, the level set consists of the $z-$axis.
- For $c<0$, the level set is the empty set.

For $c>0$, the level set is the cylinder $x^2+y^2=c$.

Is this correct??

Could I improve something??

How can we describe an intersection??

Comment: Actually,for c=0, the level set consists of the degenerate circle at the origin, whose projection curves in the xy plane consists of the lines x= +/-y.

Comment: Could you explain to me further why the level set consists of the degenerate circle at the origin?? @Mathemagician1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good so far. Now we need to describe the solutions to
$$
8\,x^2+2\,y^2+18\,z^2=c\tag{1}
$$
for $c>0$. Note that we may rewrite (1) as
$$
\frac{x^2}{u^2}+\frac{y^2}{v^2}+\frac{z^2}{w^2}=1\tag{2}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
u &= \sqrt{\frac{c}{8}} & v&= \sqrt{\frac{c}{2}} & w&= \sqrt{\frac{c}{18}}
\end{align*}
The equation (2) is exactly the equation of an [ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid). So, in summary, the level sets are

- empty for $c<0$
- the origin for $c=0$
- ellipsoids for $c>0$

Comment: Correct,but sadly,it looks like the OP changed his question.........lol

Comment: For $c>0$ does the level set consists of one ellipsoid or of all the ellipsoids for each $c$ ?? @BrianFitzpatrick